# Single Query to fill in missing column by calculating percentage of group total

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with schema as follows:

```
group    id    amount    fraction
1        1     3         
1        2     5
2        3     2
2        3     1
```

Each of the rows belongs to a group.  Each row also stores a specific value called `amount`.  I want to find the fraction of the group total `amount` that each row has, so the table will look like this:

```
AFTER

group    id    amount    fraction
1        1     3         .375
1        2     5         .625
2        3     2         66.67
2        3     1         33.33
```

To get the value for column 1, I sum up all the `amount` columns in group 1.  That would be 3+5, which is 8.  Then I divide the `amount` in row 1 by the group sum, which yields .375.  I do this for all of them.

I could do this by writing query like so:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) GROUP BY group
```

Then loop through each group, select rows in that group, calculate fractions, and update the rows.  Unfortunately this means that after the initial query I will be dealing with 2 nested for loops, and millions and millions of queries, which will take a long time given the size of the dataset.

I have a subtle feeling that there is a way to do this more efficiently with one mysql query.  If anybody has any ideas how to do this with a single query, that's my question.

Comment: group is a poor name for a table/column identifier. I wonder if you can figure out why?

Comment: Yes... I was just using that to try to make the example bare-bones simple, the names I'm actually using are different. I suppose it does make the answer a little more difficult to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single query with a `join` and aggregation:

```
select t.*, t.amount / tt.sumamount
from t join
     (select group, sum(amount) as sumamount
      from t
      group by group
     ) tt
     on t.group = tt.group;
```

EDIT:

The `update` is quite similar:

```
update t join
       (select group, sum(amount) as sumamount
        from t
        group by group
       ) tt
       on t.group = tt.group
    set fraction = t.amount / tt.sumamount;
```

Comment: Is there a way to include the `update` in the command as well so I can have the results saved?

Comment: Amazing answer!  This would have probably taken me days to figure out alone.

Comment: @user3413723 . . . practice, practice, practice.